# Cómo procesar datos y ejecutar cálculos de manera más rápida

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lo que sucede es que debo procesar una cantidad gigantesca de datos, debido a que debo encontrar una combinación eficiente a partir de una base de datos en excel

Para que tengan una idea: Si tengo 10 elementos y una base de datos de 256, debo combinar 256^10 = 1.20x10^24 posibles soluciones, por lo que mi máquina tardaría horas o incluso días.
Mi máquina tiene 16GB de ram y un procesador intel core i7 QuadCore a 2.8GHz.

He escuchado de **google colaboratory** que proporciona hardware mucho más potente para que mi código se ejecute desde ahí, pero ¿alguien ha tenido experiencia en este tipo de problemas? ¿Qué me podrían recomendar?

Porque mi problema es que mi máquina tarda mucho en procesar estos datos (mi problema es el hardware), aquí les muestro una ilustración de lo que hace mi código. (He programado en Python)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizá sea mejor opción optimizar el codigo con algunas formulas que puedas aplicar en tu caso, esto para no evaluar todas las posibilidades y puedas descartar al menos una parte del archivo o aliviar el peso del procesamiento y mejorar la eficiencia. Si dejas saber la forma de obtener esas combinaciones es posible que alguien te pueda ayudar, también te recomiendo ejecutar tu codigo con un profiling y revisarlo para saber que se consume el tiempo y mejorar ese punto.

Comment: Hay muchas formas de optimizar el código, pero estaría bien qué tipo de algoritmo exactamente estás aplcando, existen servicios en la nube para computación extrema, pero no suelen ser económicos, yo te aconsejaría optimizar el código, quizás haciendo uso de la GPU. Por ejemplo: https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python  hay más alternativas en esa línea.

Comment: Hola Daniel, sin conocer el algoritmo en si va ser difícil ayudar, por norma general lo primero es si se usa pandas o NumPy o herramientas similares vectorizar y evitar los ciclos crudos en Python en lo posible. Evitar operaciones de IO en disco en lo posible (las operaciones en RAM siempre son más rápidas, maximiza sus uso), evitar generar objetos innecesarios que exijan mucha actividad al  GC (como la concatenación de cadenas), en ciertos casos se puede detener el GC temporalmente incluso.

Comment: Usar Numba para compilación JIT de ciertas partes críticas del código no vectorizables, pasar partes críticas a C directamente con la C-API o usar Cython que además permiten liberar el GIL, usar multiprocesos para exprimir los cores de la CPU, buscar herramientas que permitan hacer uso de la GPU, muy preparada para hacer ciertos cálculos numéricos, etc, y sobre todo, no imprimas en consola si no es estrictamente necesario, es un cuello de botella muy estrecho... :)

Comment: Estimados, muy buenas todas sus sugerencias, lo que sucede es que no es problema tanto de la optimización del código sino mas bién de la cantidad de datos, todos los prints los he quitado pero aún así no acelera mucho, estoy intentando ahora tratar de focalizarlos porque no todas las combinaciones que hago necesariamente dan con mi solución.

Comment: Seria bueno que indiques con que bibliotecas estas trabajando (numpy, pandas, mysql...) para procesar y hacer consulta a los datos... Pero de mi experiencia es posible ahorrar mucha memoria definiendo los tipos de datos, si son binarios, booleanos u enteros (pandas), esto puedo ahorrar hasta un 30%... si estas empleado `pandas` y eliminando filas o usando `merge`... hay que usar `"reset_index"` esto también puede ahorrar entre un 15% a 20% de memoria

Comment: Hay unos consejos en este enlace en ingles [reducir memoria 60% a 70%](https://www.kaggle.com/gemartin/load-data-reduce-memory-usage) con código para extender un poco más lo anterior mencionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hya multiples optimizaciones segun mi experiencia como programador hace varios años. las enumerare a continuacion:

1. **Quitar todas las impresiones:** Las impresiones gastan recursos y hace que el algoritmo se demore mas en ejecutar cada instruccion.
2. **Programacion de una cache:** Debido a que son multiples datos puedes particionar el archivo y cargar cada pool a memoria, podria funcionar, el problema es cuando necesites un dato en especifico.
3. **Utilizar thread o hilos:** Puedes crear un hilo por cada thread logico que tenga tu procesador. Esto lo puedes mirar rapidamente en el administrador de tareas, tambien lo puedes obtener via codigo. Esta opcion se puede combinar con el anterior punto, con eso puedes cargar todo en memoria mas rapido.
4. **Computacion en la nube:** Amazon Web services ofrece este tipo de servicios, obviamente hay que pasar por caja para utilizar maquinas potentes
5. **HTCondor:** Esto permite utilizar multiples maquinas, si, multiples maquinas para ejecutar un mismo programa, es el overkill, y esta dentro de la computacion distribuida. Corre tando en windows como en linux, y su configuracion suele ser un poco tediosa, pero con esto se obtienen unos resultados increibles. Utilizando HTCondor mas multithreading la haces, y mas si tienes multiples computadoras en tu hogar u oficina.

Ahora, lo que no es una opcion:

1. **Google Colab:** Estas son operaciones que se hacen a nivel de CPU, el principal problema es que los procesadores que google presta gratuitamente para google collab no son tan potentes. Comparando un solo nucleo de mi ryzen 5 3600 con un unico nucleo de los procesadores de estos servidores es mas potente mi ryzen. Ademas que las soluciones de google en este aspecto son de uno a 2 nucleos como mucho. El fuerte de esta herramienta es el procesamiento por GPU y TPU, no en CPU.
2. **GPU:** La gpu/tpu es para calculos matriciales, no es para leer archivos ni nada, de hecho, de la experiencia que tengo en CUDA no hay librerias que permitan cargar archivos a la ram utilizando este tipo de hardware. De hecho, la arquitectura de la GPU como tal no es para eso.